# Can't connect to OSX lion server using Server.app locally

Tags: macos, osx-lion, osx-server

This is a case of not reading before doing.

I wanted to start clean with Lion Server, so I did what I normally do, drag the app to the trashcan and re-install it. (not realizing that server was a bit more involved than most other applications) I'm now unable to connect to the server via Server.app.

After I select the server and enter my username and password the connecting spinner spins forever. dtruss on both Server.app and servermgrd really didn't tell me much. I can connect to :311 with a web browser, so it appears that servermgrd is working to some extent.

Things I've noticed: /etc/apache2.before-restore.... directories /etc/certificates.before-restore... directories

/var/servermgrd/*.lock (with old dates)

Anyone have a clue on how to:

1. get connected to Lion Server again
2. failing that, a way to completely remove lion server so I can re-install
3. Another place to look/check etc. so I can continue debugging, I'm a bit stuck at the moment.

**Clarification:** I've installed the Lion-Server package on my desktop.  This isn't headless server hardware.

Comment: Have you tried SSH?

Comment: ssh works fine.  Server.app is the lion-server management interface.  Totally unrelated to remote login etc.

Answer (score 1):

If you do have remote login you should be able to force a reinstall of server.app from the app store. Give something like this a try:

https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/7075/how-can-i-reinstall-an-application-that-the-mac-app-store-thinks-is-installed-al

Then reinstall it.

Comment: Thanks for the link.  I'll give this a shot when I get some time this weekend.  Will update on result.

Comment: Ran through that, no difference.  (tried turning on some services by hand, starting opendirectory via launchctl forced a restore from time machine)  I think I'm going to need a full re-install